# How to aggregate analysis when processing data through pandas in chunks?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm loading a file through pandas to be processed in chunks:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

f= open("analysis.txt","a+")

chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep='\t', lineterminator='\r', chunksize=chunksize):
    my_tab = pd.crosstab(index=chunk["Year"], columns=chunk["Indicator"])
```

my_tab gives a dataframe of the Year and Indicator columns for the current chunk. Is there a way that I can aggregate all of these dataframes so that after all the data is processed, I can see the final analysis for the entire datafile?

Comment: have you tried `df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['fruit','vegi','fruit','meat','vegi','meat','fruit'],
                'ori':['us','cn','cn','nz','nz','us','cn'],
               'num':[5,5,9,3,2,10,8],
               'price':[5,5,10,3,3,13,20]})
df1 = df.iloc[0:2]
df2 = df.iloc[2:4]
df3 = df.iloc[4:7] # chunk
a = pd.crosstab(df1['type'], df1['ori'])
b = pd.crosstab(df2['type'], df2['ori'])
c = pd.crosstab(df3['type'], df3['ori']) # crosstab of chunks
```

use reduce to make life easier:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda df1, df2:df1.add(df2, fill_value=0) ,[a, b, c])
```

result:

```
ori     cn  nz  us   
type             
fruit   2.0 0.0 1.0  
meat    0.0 1.0 1.0  
vegi    1.0 1.0 0.0
```

This should be almost as same as:

```
pd.crosstab(df['type'], df['ori'])
```